# How to get Image from a URL

Tags: ios4, uiimageview

Kindly tell me how can i get `UIImage` from a URL if i have URL from a `JSon` Get. I have been searching and found some tips but not succeeded yet. Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tips? and what is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple in my point of view. Just use the following line of codes:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com/imageName.png/jpg"];`

`NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

`UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData] autorelease];`

Now use this image wherever you want. Hope this helps.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
                    [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString:@"http.yourimageurl.jpg/png"]]];

img_imageOperatorimg.image=myImage;
```

Hope This helps